# how to set a static HTML page as my homepage in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a coded webpage (written outside Wordpress with HTML and CSS) that I want to set as the homepage of my Wordpress website. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can select a static page as a homepage from Settings->Reading->Your homepage displays->A static page->Homepage

Create a new template in the theme directory with the copied HTML and select it from the dropdown that will appear on the homepage.

The styles are going in style.css